# Find the Word Pair - Codewars 5 kyu

Tags: python, optimization

**Hello everyone, I have a problem with 5-kyu kata:**

*Given an array of words and a target compound word, your objective is to find the two words which combine into the target word, returning both words in the order they appear in the array, and their respective indices in the order they combine to form the target word. Words in the array you are given may repeat, but there will only be one unique pair that makes the target compound word. If there is no match found, return null/nil/None.*

*Examples:*

*fn(['super','bow','bowl','tar','get','book','let'], "superbowl")      =>   ['super','bowl',   [0,2]]*

*fn(['bow','crystal','organic','ally','rain','line'], "crystalline")   =>   ['crystal','line', [1,5]]*

*fn(['bow','crystal','organic','ally','rain','line'], "rainbow")       =>   ['bow','rain',     [4,0]]*

*fn(['bow','crystal','organic','ally','rain','line'], "organically")   =>   ['organic','ally', [2,3]]*

*fn(['top','main','tree','ally','fin','line'], "mainline")             =>   ['main','line',    [1,5]]*

*fn(['top','main','tree','ally','fin','line'], "treetop")              =>   ['top','tree',     [2,0]]*

[This kata on Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5aaae0f5fd8c069e8c00016e/train/python)

**I got a solution:**

```
def compound_match(words, target):
#check input
if words == None or target == None:
    return None

#find solution
indx = []
result = []
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    for k in range(i+1, len(words)):
        if words[i]+words[k] == target:
            indx[0:1] = i, k
            result[0:2] = words[i], words[k], indx
            return result
        elif words[k]+words[i] == target:
            indx[0:1] = k, i
            result[0:2] = words[i], words[k], indx
            return result
return None
```

**I pass TEST, pass "Some very short random tests" and "Some short random tests", but cant pass "Some very long random tests" and got error:**

```
STDERR
Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)
```

**I understand that my code is not optimal or perfect, but what can I do to improve?**

Comment: you could use directly `return [words[i], words[k], [i,k]]` without using lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete solution.

```
def compound_match(words, target):
    if words is None or target is None:
        return None

    word_dict = {w:i for i, w in enumerate(words)}

    for i, w in enumerate(words):
        w = words[i]
        if target.startswith(w):
            tail = target[len(w):]
            if tail in word_dict:
                k = word_dict[tail]
                idx = [i, k]
                result = [words[min(i,k)], words[max(i,k)], idx]
                return result

    return None
```

When run on the sampe input, it produces the following:

```
['super', 'bowl', [0, 2]]
['crystal', 'line', [1, 5]]
['bow', 'rain', [4, 0]]
['organic', 'ally', [2, 3]]
['main', 'line', [1, 5]]
['top', 'tree', [2, 0]]
```

Note:  I left out any check for duplicate words, or for `i` and `k` being the same.  It can be adapted to handle that, although the constraints about duplicate words, or a target that consists of the same word repeated, weren't entirely clear to me.

However, I did paste it into the code wars link from your post, and it said it passed all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Prob. you can speed up by using the *set* idea, like this:

I think it will work, did not do much testing though. Let me know if you find out it helps.

```py
def compound_match(words, target):
      
    S = set(words)
    
    for i in range(1, len(target)):
        x, y = target[:i], target[i:]
        if x in S and y in S:
            ix, iy = words.index(x), words.index(y)
            ordered = [x, y] if ix < iy else [y, x]
            return [*ordered, [ix, iy]]
```